# How to support multiple environments/DNS in Selenium Grid?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, dns, automated-tests, selenium-grid

I have a suite of automated tests that run on a Selenium Grid. I have a need now to run these tests in multiple environments (QA, Stage, Production). The environments will be set up using a different DNS server for each one. So a test targeting the QA environment should use the QA DNS, Stage tests should use the Stage DNS, etc.

Ideally, I would like my test suite (which runs in Jenkins and accepts a parameter for which environment to target) to be able to tell the grid to allocate a node, set its DNS servers to (whatever), run the test, then put the DNS servers back the way it found them.

I don't see anything in Selenium's documentation about changing DNS settings on the individual nodes. I also tried looking for browser capabilities that could handle this, but no luck there either. What's the cleanest way to make this happen?

EDIT: The requirement to switch DNS servers is a new one, so there's currently no method in place (manual or automatic) for doing it. Before using this DNS-based method of differentiating environments, we were using environment-specific hostfiles, and switching between them with a custom service that listened on each node for a hostfile-switch request. We might have to create a similar service for switching DNS settings, but I was hoping there was something more "official" than that.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier for your tests to form the respective environment's URL properly and then launch the tests ? What sort of changes are you expecting to be done in DNS for this ? Usually a QA env URL is different from a Production one.. so as long as your test launches a QA env URL you should be hitting the QA env.. Wouldn't that work ?

Comment: Our URLs are the same regardless of environment. QA, Production, they all look alike. We were managing this with environment-specific hostfiles up until now, the DNS method is new.

Comment: Can you please help explain as to how do you do this DNS settings manually ? Maybe that can give an idea on how it can be done in an automated fashion

Comment: I added some more information in the post to address this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We worked around this issue by setting up a proxy server for each environment, and configuring the proxy servers to use the environment-specific DNS settings. Selenium permits setting a proxy on the individual nodes, so this was a way to programatically modify those settings.